# Testing a multi-platform project

Tags: test-management, efficiency

We have an Android app that also has an online portal.
Currently, two teams of developers are working on the Android and the web part separately.
the process is being tracked using two separate Trello boards because there are different parts in the platforms.
right now we have to test four different situations (Android -> Web, Web -> Android, Web -> Web, Android -> Android) for every little change and it is confusing and too hard and also time-consuming.
The four situations are to see whether the changes a client makes, take effect on both sides and to make sure the platforms are synced or not.
Also, know that the web part contains the management and reporting system for admins to have control over the clients to some extends.
Is there any other way to organize this and make the testing more efficient?

Comment: Can you give some more detail?  Why are there two different test teams?  What are the four situations that have to be tested for each change?  How is project management being done?  Is the Android app completely dependent on the web portal, or can it run separately?  Does the web portal provide functionality above and beyond what the Android app does?

Comment: Added the details you asked for @KevinMcKenzie

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your development model, but here are some ideas:

- Were the 2 teams used because of expertise in Android and web apps?
- Have you used some stub code to test the android and web sections separately to make sure their basic logic works?
- You can test the within platform sections (web-web) with the teams you have using simulated data/inputs/outputs.
- Once you need to test the entire flow, why not combine Android and Web testers so that they can run through the entire process and each group can identify errors in their specialty areas.

And have you created a development schedule with cutoffs for releases so all testing groups can plan accordingly? Even with Agile, your team needs to know when testing occurs so that developers and testers can concentrate on that work.

Comment: Well, we are a small company and there is only one tester for both of the platforms. the problem is with the four different situations to test when a change is made.